# How to get rid of power button above matplotlib nbagg plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I plot graphs in IPython notebook using the nbagg backend, I get a graph with a power button toolbar above it:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("nbagg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to remove this toolbar? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter 4.3.1 and matplotlib 2.0.0 I am able to hide it by adding

```
button.btn.btn-mini.btn-primary { 
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

to my custom stylesheet (`~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`, you might need to create the directories and file first). After updating the file, restart your notebook server.